# Почему на пустое поле вместо null отправляет 0 метод post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, crud

есть модель . Когда я делаю добавление printingEdition в базу данных, я хочу что б все поля были обязательными. При добавлении я специально не указываю поле price для проверки, при добавлении оно ж должно вернуть null и добавление прекратится, а у меня возвращает 0 и добавление проходит успешно. Подскажите почему

```
 public class PrintingEditionModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.Errors.TITLE_IS_REQUIRED)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.Errors.DESCRIPTION_IS_REQUIRED)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.Errors.PRICE_IS_REQUIRED)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.Errors.CURRENCY_IS_REQUIRED)]
        public CurrencyType Currency { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.Errors.TYPE_IS_REQUIRED)]
        public PrintingType Type { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.Errors.AUTHOR_IS_REQUIRED)]
        public List<long> AuthorsId { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Поймите разницу между

```
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

и

```
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

один не может иметь null а второй может. И первый по умолмолчанию 0

Comment: я понимаю , вот мне и нужно что б ```public decimal Price { get; set; }``` не могло быть null

Comment: @Dmitriy, так оно у Вас и не может быть null, оно по умолчанию равно 0.0

Comment: @Serafim Prozorov ок, теперь понял

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.7): "Значение по умолчанию Decimal равно 0."
Это же `ValueType`, откуда там `null` возьмётся, если вы не сделаете сами это поле `Nullable`?

Comment: Хорошо, насчет decimal я понял, ну у меня та же проблема и с enum

Comment: про enum я тоже уже понял

Comment: @Dmitriy Вы будете смеяться, но "По умолчанию память, используемая для перечисления, инициализируется средой CLR равным нулю." ))

Comment: @ CrazyElf  хах, понял) Спасибо